# How to use Creation Kit to make Nightingale Blade benefit from Daedric Smithing Perk

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

"The blade is not affected by any smithing perks.
PC Only This issue has been addressed by the Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Patch; it causes the weapon to benefit from the Daedric Smithing perk." UESP

How do I replicate this feature in USSEP using Creation Kit?

Comment: Hi cyber, welcome to Arqade! Please link to the source and use proper punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if an item is temperable, but does not benefit from a smithing perk, this is usually a result of the item lacking an appropriate material keyword. Find the Weapon record for any Daedric weapon (should have one of [these FormIDs](https://pt.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric#Daedric_Weapons)), look in its keyword list for a keyword indicating that it is a Daedric weapon (I would guess that the name would be `WeaponMaterialDaedric`, or something along those lines), and then add the same keyword to (each leveled version of) the [Nightingale Blade](https://pt.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Blade). You probably also want to create a tempering recipe for `NightingaleBlade05`; these are under Constructible Objects, and you can just copy and modify the one for `NightingaleBlade04`.

(Hint: To quickly find the relevant COBJ record, right click `NightingaleBlade04` in the Weapons list and choose "Use Info" - this will pop up a window of everything in the game that references that record, including its tempering recipe.)